# ¿Cómo limpiar los datos de mi barchart de MPAndroidChart en una consulta con filtrado?

Tags: java, android, volley, mpandroidchart

Mi consulta es la siguiente:

Estoy consumiendo un servicio rest que consulta datos con volley y los muestro en un gráfico usando MPAndroidChart, el problema es que cada consulta que realizo a traves de 2 fechas que ingreso se queda la información anterior almacenada en el gráfico.
Y lo que deseo es que no suceda eso y solo muestre la información que se consulta.

Ingreso 2 fechas como filtrado para hacer una nueva consulta al servicio REST.

Ya probé con barChart.invalidate() y no me funcionó

Mi código:

```
mostrarDatos("2021-11-2", Utiles.obtenerFechaActual("GMT -3"));
        btnFiltrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String desde = btnDesde.getText().toString();
                String hasta= btnHasta.getText().toString();
                if(desde.equals("Desde") || hasta.equals("Hasta"))
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Debe ingresar fecha desde y hasta", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else {
                    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    try {
                        Date date1 = dateFormat.parse(desde);
                        Date date2 = dateFormat.parse(hasta);
                        if(date1.before(date2))
                            mostrarDatos(desde, hasta);
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Fecha hasta debe ser mayor a fecha desde", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } // fin else
            }
        }); //FIL BOTON FILTRAR
```

Método **mostrarDatos**:

```
public void mostrarDatos(String desde, String hasta) {
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                grupos= new String[jsonArray.length()];
                for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++) {
                    total_reservas = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("total_reservas");
                    grupos[i] = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("descripcion") ;
                    entradas.add(new BarEntry(i, Integer.parseInt(total_reservas)));
                }
                crearGraficoBarra();
                legend(barChart); //metodo leyenda
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> parametros = new HashMap<String, String>();
            parametros.put("fecha_desde", desde);
            parametros.put("fecha_hasta", hasta);
            return parametros;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    requestQueue.add(request);
}
```

Método **crearGraficoBarra**:

```
private void crearGraficoBarra() {
    //mandamos los datos para crear la gráfica
    BarDataSet datos = new BarDataSet(entradas ,"");

    BarData data = new BarData(datos);

    //ponemos color a cada barra
    datos.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
    datos.setValueTextSize(18);
    datos.setValueTextColor(Color.BLACK);

    //separacion entre las barras
    data.setBarWidth(0.45f);
    barChart.setData(data);

    barChart.setFitBars(true); //pone las barras centradas
    barChart.setDrawGridBackground(true); //las lineas que sean horizontales unicamente
    barChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false); //no mostrar las leyendas

    Description description = new Description();
    description.setText(""); //para que no muestre descripcion
    barChart.setDescription(description);

    ejeX(barChart.getXAxis());
    ejeY(barChart.getAxisRight()); //que muestre a la izquierda
    //LAS 2 siguientes lineas son para que cargue los datos sin hacer clic en el grafico
    barChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
    barChart.invalidate();
}
```

Metodo **legend**:

```
private void legend(BarChart barChart) {
    Legend legend = barChart.getLegend();
    legend.setFormToTextSpace(2);
    //datos que van a ir en la leyenda
    ArrayList<LegendEntry>entries = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i< grupos.length;i++) {
        LegendEntry entry = new LegendEntry();
        entry.label= grupos[i];
        entries.add(entry);
    }
    legend.setCustom(entries);
}
```

Adjunto capturas para mostrar como se visualiza luego de realizar otra consulta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes crear un método similar a `crearGraficoBarra()` pero en este caso eliminaría los datos y volvería a dibujar el gráfico vacío:

```
private void limpiaGraficoBarra() {
    //Elimina datos
    entradas = entradas.clear()
    //mandamos los datos para crear la gráfica

    BarDataSet datos = new BarDataSet(entradas ,"");
    BarData data = new BarData(datos);    
    barChart.setData(data);

    barChart.invalidate();
    barChart.clear();

}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!! Me sirvió!! Saludos